# Data Loader Error: Too many batch retries

Tags: apex

I've searched on SO for a solution to this problem, but haven't found anything other than a link to why the problem happens which is here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_bulk_exceptions.htm

I created a "before" trigger on the Lead object with the goal to prevent duplicate leads.

I have a bunch of leads I'm trying to insert using Data Loader.  My before trigger calls an apex class that checks the database to see if a lead exists based on company name, and if it does, uses the addError() to return an error.  Based on the above link, data loader will keep trying to insert those records multiple times which doesn't really help me.  If a record already exists, I just want it to skip to the next one instead of retrying multiple times which seems to be the reason this error happens.

The specific error is:  Error: Too many batch retries in the presence of Apex triggers and partial failures

Is there a way I can use Data Loader to bulk load my leads without getting this error?  Maybe another way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 4):

The Data Loader isn't your problem: your trigger is. The Data Loader, by default, uses `allOrNone=false` and `batchSize=200`. When `allOrNone` is set to `false`, a single record in a batch that fails to save won't fail the entire transaction. When `allOrNone` is set to `true`, then any single validation causes an entire batch to fail, which is usually not useful.

So, when `allOrNone` is `false`, the system tries to insert the entire batch. If any records fail because of a validation error, then those records are "set aside" with the error recorded, and the system tries to process the remaining records. If any records fail because of a validation error, then those that generated an error the second time are also "set aside" with their errors recorded, and the system tries the remaining records. At this point, *any validation error* on a record will cause the entire transaction to abort with the "too many tries" error.

So, odds are, your trigger is probably aborting after the first error without checking the remaining values, so when the system retries a second time, a different record is caught, so the system retries a third time, finds a third error, and gives up. You need to make sure your trigger is processing every record in the transaction, even if a single record has an error. If you don't do this, you'll continue to get "too many retry" errors if you manage to get three errors in a batch.

Alternatively, you could set `batchSize` to 2 in the Data Loader (see the Options menu), but this will have an adverse performance on the amount of time it takes to upload and rapidly consume API calls. You'd be better off doing the right thing, and fixing your trigger. While I've described what's going on, you haven't included any code, so you'll want to ask that as a separate question so it can get the attention it deserves.

Comment: the allOrNone retry mechanism can also play havoc with trigger recursion guards if not implemented correctly - as I found out to my chagrin one long weekend of diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question. So if I want to go down the path of fixing my trigger based on what you're saying, instead of using addError(), I could potentially use some list or other collection to filter out the records that have errors so that way the batch won't halt?

Comment: @user28908 No, addError is the correct way to do things. What I'm saying is that you should try to error as many records as necessary on the first pass. If you stop after the first addError, then you'll end up creating a situation where you can get the "too many retries" error.